# How to add each line of string in a List string in flutter?

Tags: string, list, flutter

I have this string in input

```
" 
01/05/2020
12/02/2020
13/03/2020
24/05/2020
25/06/2020
"
```

I search to add this string in a Liststring

like that

```
["01/05/2020","12/02/2020","13/03/2020","24/05/2020","25/06/2020"]
```

Comment: `yourString.split('\n')`

Comment: thank you, I will try